# GQL: Multiple Query Execution

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, graphql-js

We are using GraphQL using apollo-server, we are trying to execute multiple queries in a single Query Operation as described below.

I expect that both queries should execute and provide their results.

```
query Operation1 {
 getPosts: {
   id
   title
   url
 }
 getBooks: {
   id
   title   
 }
}
```

Now in the above case, if both queries are successful, then we are getting results for both given below.

```
{
  "data": {
    "getPosts": [{
      "id": "P1",
      "title": "post1",
      "url": "/blog/post1"
    }],
    "getBooks": [{
      "id": "B1",
      "title": "book1"
    }]    
  } 
}
```

But if in case any of query fails, the result is only represented as errors.

```
{
  "data": {},
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "failure message",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "getBooks"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am not sure if this is the desired behavior because my expectation was as follows.

```
{
  "data": {
    "getPosts": [
      {
        "id": "P1",
        "title": "post1",
        "url": "/blog/post1"
      }
    ],
    "getBooks": {
      "data": {},
      "errors": [
        {
          "message": "failure message",
          "locations": [
            {
              "line": 2,
              "column": 3
            }
          ],
          "path": [
            "getBooks"
          ],
          "extensions": {
            "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the apollo docs: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#inspecting-error-states

> Inspecting error states
>
> providing the errorPolicy configuration option to the useQuery hook.
> The default value is none, which tells Apollo Client to treat all
> GraphQL errors as runtime errors. In this case, Apollo Client discards
> any query response data returned by the server and sets the error
> property in the useQuery result object.
>
> If you set errorPolicy to all, useQuery does not discard query
> response data, allowing you to render partial results.
>
> For more information, see [Handling operation errors](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/error-handling).

Comment: Appreciate your response, but we are getting above kind of error in GQL server side where we are using "Apllo-Server V4" nothing specific to any client. Our server it self does not give desired set of result. @SlothOverlord

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is to look at your server logs, not your browser logs. It says you're getting an internal server error.

Second, what you've listed here is not a valid GraphQL query syntax. What you have:

```
query Operation1 {
 getPosts: {
   id
   title
   url
 }
 getBooks: {
   id
   title   
 }
}
```

What I assume you're trying to do is done without colons:

```
query Operation1 {
 getPosts {
   id
   title
   url
 }
 getBooks {
   id
   title   
 }
}
```

Additionally, the output you're looking for is not what you would get if done correctly. `data` is the success of your entire operation (not each query). `errors` are the failures in the entire operation.

```json
{
  "data": {
    "getPosts": [
      {
        "id": "P1",
        "title": "post1",
        "url": "/blog/post1"
      }
    ],
    "getBooks": []
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Some error message",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "getBooks"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "SOME_ERROR_CODE_HERE"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

Colons are used to create aliases, so that you can do the SAME query multiple  times in one operation:

```
query Operation1 {
 getAllPosts: getPosts {
   id
   title
   url
 }
 getPostsFiltered: getPosts(filter: "something") {
   id
   title
   url
 }
}
```

This would give you a result similar to this:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "getAllPosts": [
      {
        "id": "P1",
        "title": "post1",
        "url": "/blog/post1"
      }
    ],
    "getPostsFiltered": []
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @DanCrews for your answer. I agree aligned there are some syntax mistakes on the above question but the intention is to make 2 different queries without aliases. Also, the response I have added is not correct which you corrected. 

But on my apollo-server I am not getting the response that you are mentioning. Version I am using is ""@apollo/server": "4.9.5".

Please help me get it resolved.